# Simple code coverage tool for netbeans 7.3

Tags: plugins, netbeans, code-coverage

I am looking for a decent code coverage tool which will work with Netbeans 7.3 AND jdk 1.7 for webbased projects. Unfortunately, due to circumstances, I am not able to use maven.

I have searched, downloaded, and installed the plugin from here http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38945 . After restarting, the coverage option for my project is there, but it is not selectable.

After searching the net some more, it turns out that 'emma' that helps run the plugin does not support JDK 1.7 yet. Somewhere else I read that it might also be because the project I am working on is a web application (Apache Wickets). So I might actually have 2 problems :/.

I also downloaded some Cobertura plugin (intended for Netbeans 7.2, but I installed it anyway) but I cant find an easy way of using it. Searching for a way to use this plugin involves some build script adjustments, and if I read it right, you need to do that for every project.... that just doesn't seem very efficient.

I wondered if anybody else has something useful for this situation or if there is an update on it, because there was a thread on StackOverflow concerning code coverage for Netbeans 7.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the plugin, recently created for NetBeans IDE 7.3: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/48570/tikione-jacocoverage

Comment: tikione-jacocoverage is okay for Java Application, Java Library and Java Project with Existing Sources only. See http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/48570/?show=true